# How to reset nested Ordered Lists after using a counter

Tags: css, frontend

I’m adding a privacy policy to a site and I’ve marked up the content with lots of nested lists…

This is the output I am wanting:

```
1  
   1.1  
   1.2
      a
      b
         i
         ii
         ii
      c
   1.3  
   1.4   
2
   2.1
   2.2
   2.3
3
```

This CSS is getting the numbering right for the 1st and 2nd level I’m just not sure how to reset the 3rd level to `lower-alpha` and 4th level to `lower-roman`

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  li{
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ") ";
    counter-increment: item
  }
  ol {
    /* Second level that is coming out as 1.2 correctly */
    ol {
      /* Third level - how do I reset this to just be lower-alpha??? */
      li {

      }
      li:before {

      }
      ol {
        li {

        }
        li:before {

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    line-height: 26px;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item
}
ol  ol {
    /* Second level that is coming out as 1.2 correctly */
}
ol ol ol {
    /* Third level - how do I reset this to just be lower-alpha??? */
    list-style-type: lower-latin
}
ol ol ol li:before {
    content: '';
    counter-increment: none;
}
ol ol ol ol {
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>bbb</li>
  <li>
      <ol>
          <li>aaa</li>
          <li>bbb</li>
          <li>
              <ol>
                  <li>aaa</li>
                  <li>bbb</li>
                  <li>
                      <ol>
                          <li>aaa</li>
                          <li>bbb</li>
                      </ol>
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </li>
      </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```